# Add new rows with count = 0 present in others groupby group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this TABLE:

```
||ID || Group || Status   
|| 1 ||  AAAA ||  aaaaa  
|| 2 ||  AAAA ||  bbbbb  
|| 3 ||  BBBB || aaaaa   
|| 4 ||  BBBB ||  bbbbb  
|| 5 ||  BBBB ||  aaaaa    
|| 6 ||  BBBB ||  ccccc   
|| 7 ||  BBBB ||  ddddd
```

I want as result of my query:

```
|| Status || Group || Count(Status)  
|| aaaaa || AAAA  || 1  
|| bbbbb || AAAA  || 1  
|| ccccc || AAAA  || 0   
|| ddddd || AAAA  || 0 
|| aaaaa || BBBB  || 2  
|| bbbbb || BBBB  || 1  
|| ccccc || BBBB  || 1  
|| ddddd || BBBB  || 1
```

I tried:

```
select status, count(status), group  
    from TABLE  
    group by status, group
```

But this code can't add the lines with count = 0

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to generate all combinations of `status` and `group`. You can do this by using `CROSS JOIN`. Then, do a `LEFT JOIN` on your table to get the `COUNT`

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e38a/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        a.[group], b.[status]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [group] FROM YourTable
    )a
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [status] FROM YourTable
    )b
)
SELECT
    c.[status],
    c.[group],
    ISNULL(COUNT(t.Id), 0) AS StatusCount
FROM Cte c
LEFT JOIN YourTable t
    ON t.[status] = c.status
    AND t.[group] = c.[group]
GROUP BY c.[status], c.[group]
```

---

Using a subquery:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e38a/2/0)

```
SELECT
    c.[status],
    c.[group],
    ISNULL(COUNT(t.Id), 0) AS StatusCount
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT
            a.[group], b.[status]
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT [group] FROM YourTable
        )a
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT [status] FROM YourTable
        )b
    )t
) c
LEFT JOIN YourTable t
    ON t.[status] = c.status
    AND t.[group] = c.[group]
GROUP BY c.[status], c.[group]
```